# Splitting a String in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I am trying to split a string in unix shell script, but I am not able to figure out. Any help would be appreciated.
Below is the example

```
    olap4j-xmla-1.0.1.500,

    olap4j-xmla-1.2.0,

    olap4j-xmla-1.2.0.SNAPSHOT,

    olap4j-xmla-1.2.0.RELEASE
```

The above strings will be split so that the output will be stored in different variables like

```
  var1=olap4j-xmla    var2=1.0.1.500

  var1=olap4j-xmla    var2=1.2.0

  var1=olap4j-xmla    var2=1.2.0    var3=SNAPSHOT

  var1=olap4j-xmla    var2=1.2.0    var3=RELEASE
```

Comment: You haven't explained the conditions for setting `var3`.  In the first and second examples, should `var3` be unset or should it be set to the empty string?  In the first example, why is it not `var1=olap4j-xmla`, `var2=1.0.1`, and `var3=500`?  How should `olap4j-xmla-1.2.0a` be handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using string substitutions:

```
s='olap4j-xmla-1.0.1.500'
read var1 var2 <<< "${s%-*} ${s##*-}"
```

Now check variables:

```
declare -p var1 var2
declare -- var1="olap4j-xmla"
declare -- var2="1.0.1.500"
```

---

**Update:**

Thanks to comment from pjh below I have realized that OP needs 3 variable for some cases instead of 2.

Looking at that I think following `sed` will work better:

```
sed -E 's/^(.+)-([0-9.]+)(\.([^0-9]+))?$/\1 \2 \4/' <<< "olap4j-xmla-1.2.0.SNAPSHOT"
olap4j-xmla 1.2.0 SNAPSHOT

sed -E 's/^(.+)-([0-9.]+)(\.([^0-9]+))?$/\1 \2 \4/' <<< "olap4j-xmla-1.2.0"
olap4j-xmla 1.2.0
```

Output of `sed` can be fed into `read` as shown in above examples.

Comment: Great solution to use the string substitutions.

Comment: @anubhava good answer. Sometimes it is useful to use arrays: declare -a arr="(${s%-*} ${s##*-})"; echo ${arr[0]}; echo ${arr[1]}

Comment: This doesn't deal with the cases where `var3` needs to be set.

Comment: In `sed -E 's/^(.+)-.....` you can do without `^(.+)` and start with the last `-`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read LINE; do
  var1=$(cut -d '-' -f1,2 <<< "$LINE")
  tmp=$(cut -d '-' -f3 <<< "$LINE")
  var2=$(sed 's/\(.*\)\.[a-zA-Z]*$/\1/' <<< "$tmp")
  var3=$(sed -n 's/.*\.\([a-zA-Z]*$\)/\1/p' <<< "$tmp")
  echo -e "var1=$var1; var2=$var2; var3=$var3"
done < file.txt
```

Output:

```
  var1=olap4j-xmla; var2=1.0.1.500; var3=
  var1=olap4j-xmla; var2=1.2.0; var3=
  var1=olap4j-xmla; var2=1.2.0; var3=SNAPSHOT
  var1=olap4j-xmla; var2=1.2.0; var3=RELEASE
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? Seems like a reasonable approach?

Comment: This doesn't deal with the cases where `var3` needs to be set.

Comment: My bad @pjh. I fixed the issue.